# Ionic react component is not getting imported

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-react

I am trying to import IonAccordion and IonAccordionGroup, but I'm facing error like
"Line 38:16:  'IonAccordionGroup' is not defined  react/jsx-no-undef".
And I'm using library type as react for ionic app development. And latest version of ionic and react.
[Here I've attached the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3eQaf.png)

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

This should be as simple as including the following lines at the top of your **Menu.tsx** file:

```
import React from 'react';
import { IonAccordionGroup } from '@ionic/react';
```

Note that [IonAccordion](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/accordion) is a new component for Ionic React 6 and you will need to upgrade to version 6 if you are using an older version of Ionic React.